# Does a transfer in a Schengen country airport count as time in that country for US Travel restriction?

Tags: usa, air-travel, schengen, covid-19

I'm due to fly from the UK with IcelandAir, from Glasgow, via Reykjavik in Iceland (a Schengen country) on 30th March, to Florida. The stop-over in Iceland is approx 2.5 hours.

Does anyone know if this would count as time in a Schengen country (even though I won't leave the airport)?

IcelandAir's website states "You are affected by the travel restrictions if you have been in a Schengen country at any point in the 14 days before your planned entry date to the US."

Do you think the airport connection means I will have been in a Schengen country in the 14 days before"?  I realise the word before is ambiguous because it may not apply to the current day.

Any comments welcome.

Comment: The exact wording is: **were physically present within the Schengen Area during the 14-day period preceding their entry**, so the current day counts since you **were physically present within**